# Wine6 in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: wine

I just updated my Ubuntu machine to the latest Ubuntu 21.10 and I can't find a way to update also Wine from v5 to v6. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Update to 21.10 is not even available yet. You must have installed the beta which is off topic. If you want to use 21.10 with community support, I suggest that you wait until it's actually released and then you should cleanly install 21.10.  In the meantime, please report all issues on Launchpad and thank you for testing Ubuntu.

Comment: See also: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283)

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no deb packages for Wine v6 yet.

See the [Debian Package Tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/wine) for the rundown of reasons why not.

Fundamentally, as of late 2021, the Debian Wine volunteers need more help from their fellow Wine users to overcome the blockers they have encountered.